# Dummit and Foote example of finding a Gröbner basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I came across the following example of finding a Gröbner basis using Buchberger's Algorithm in Dummit and Foote.

[a screenshot of the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtHwh.png)

Here is a summary of the example:
Choose the lexicographic ordering $x>y$ on $F[x,y]$, where $F$ is a field, and consider the ideal $I$ generated by $f_1 = x^3y-xy^2+1$ and $f_2 = x^2y^2-y^3-1$.
Using Buchberger's Algorithm, we conclude that $G = \{f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4\}$ is a Gröbner basis for $I$, where $f_3 = x+y$ and $f_4 = y^4-y^3-1$. Then the author proceeds to claim that the ideal of leading terms $LT(I) = (x^3y, x^2y^2,x,y^4) = (x, y^4)$.

What I don't understand is why we have $(x^3y, x^2y^2,x,y^4) = (x, y^4)$. To my understanding, in order for the two ideals to be equal we need to be able to write $x^3y$ and $x^2y^2$ as sums of multiples of $x$ and $y^4$, but I don't see a way of doing that.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos, thanks for your suggestion. A summary of the example has been added to the question.

Comment: you want $x^2y^2 = \alpha x + \beta y^4$ for some $\alpha, \beta \in F[x,y]$, and similarly for the other one. Can you think of any good choices for $\alpha, \beta$?

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph I can take $\alpha = xy^2$ and $\beta = 0$! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generators $x^3y$ and $x^2y^2$ are multiples of the other generator $x$, so they are redundant.